# How do I display an Excel (or any) document with Custom Masterpage Applied?

Tags: 2007, master-page

I created a custom "master page" for our SharePoint site.  On this site, my users need to have the Excel/Word documents open up "on the page", instead of opening up in Excel/Word/etc.  I'm fairly new to SharePoint development, so please feel free to point out if I'm missing something fairly simple!

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Are you able to give an example of where you've seen behaviour similar to this? The closest thing I can think of for what you describe is "Office Web Apps" which I believe is only available for SharePoint 2010. This is a lot more than a masterpage customisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the default behavior for IE is to open Office documents in the browser via the plugin, which I think is what you want.  Most of the help you'll find scouring the web is people wanting to go the other way: to force it to open in the Office client.  Here is Microsoft's official support document on the topic:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059

I cannot find anything to walk you through the reverse of this, but perhaps you could reverse engineer the steps in this document to come up with your solution.

I think what you are saying is that you want your master page to be visible/active when the user opens a document, and you want said document to be displayed in the editable region of the page.  I don't think this is possible in SharePoint 2007.  The problem is going to be that the browser plugin will open the documents full-screen anyway, hiding your master page.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  This has lead me down the path of creating a web part page to display my spreadsheet "in the window".  Now to troubleshoot some menu issues!